# DataTable HTML in Add Rows new object[]

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I created a DataTable and I am adding new rows with `new object[]`.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Hello", "World", "<i>Test</i>" });
```

In the `object[]` array I got some values that are shown in the `DataTable`.

I would like to add some `HTML` styling, is this possible like above? I would like to have the `Test` shown as italic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataTable` stores data, it it not responsible for any format or styling. So it depends on where you want to diplay it, if it's an `ASP.NET`-`GridView` you could use the `RowDataBound` event. [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should work to prevent that your html will be encoded:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
       e.Row.Cells[0].Text = Server.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes indeed, I tried another styling in RowDataBound aswell and that works, but my question is really specific to object[]

Comment: @TheOddGuy: then it makes no sense or i don't understand it. In what way is the `DataTable` or the `object[]` responsible for any formatting? It stores objects, strings in this case. You can store the HTML in the `DataTable`, assign that as `DataSource` to the `GridView`. Then it should work.

Comment: I am looping through different lists with different objects and showing some properties of different objects in a datatable. I would like to give some cells another color since they are from another object type. So I have to do it in the loop because I think I am not able to get the object type in the RowDataBound by the property value

Comment: _"I am not able to get the object type in the RowDataBound by the property value"_ Why not? You can access every row's field for example by the columns name or by the ordinal index. You just have to cast `e.Row.DataItem` to `DataRowView` and use it's `Row` property to get the actual `DataRow`.

Comment: Ehm for example: List<User> users; foreach(User u in users) { dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {u.Name});} How can I know in the RowDataBound that the object from the value in the datatable is a type of User?

Comment: @TheOddGuy: by adding this info as column to the table.

Comment: Uhm what if the column name consists other not object relevant data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56192/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-theoddguy).